# Unable to extract content from DOM element with $0 thru BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, dom, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[Here is the website I am to scrape the number of reviews](https://www.thebodyshop.com/en-us/body/lotion-and-cream/british-rose-instant-glow-body-lotion/p/p000627)[image: The HTML code I am trying to scrape]

So here i want to extract number 272 but it returns None everytime .
I have to use BeautifulSoup.
I tried-

```
sources = requests.get('https://www.thebodyshop.com/en-us/body/body-butter/olive-body-butter/p/p000016')

soup = BeautifulSoup(sources.content, 'lxml')

x = soup.find('div', {'class': 'columns five product-info'}).find('div')

print(x)
```

output - empty tag

I want to go inside that tag further.

Comment: Why do so many people think that the word is "scrap" rather than "scrape?

Comment: Where is `class="column five product-info"` in the HTML?

Comment: What does `$0` have to do with this?

Comment: @Barmar I corrected the spelling, thanks. Pls check my link again.

Comment: The image should be the relevant part of the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of reviews is dynamically retrieved from an url you can find in network tab. You can simply extract from response.text with regex. The endpoint is part of a defined ajax handler.

You can find a lot of the API instructions in one of the js files: `https://thebodyshop-usa.ugc.bazaarvoice.com/static/6097redes-en_us/bvapi.js`

For example:

[image]

You can trace back through a whole lot of jquery if you really want.

tl;dr; I think you need only add the `product_id` to a constant string.

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

p = re.compile(r'"numReviews":(\d+),')
ids = ['p000627']

with requests.Session() as s:
    for product_id in ids:
        r = s.get(f'https://thebodyshop-usa.ugc.bazaarvoice.com/6097redes-en_us/{product_id}/reviews.djs?format=embeddedhtml')
        p = re.compile(r'"numReviews":(\d+),')
        print(int(p.findall(r.text)[0]))
```

Comment: hi QHarr, thanks for this solution. it works , but how did you get the bazaarvoice url. and can i do this dynamic extract using BeautifulSoup? Also, how do i iterate over 100s of URLs for extracting review counts?

Comment: Thanks QHarr, thats what I did, made a for loop for product IDs...in a constant string

Comment: hi again, i am trying similar code for getting ratings, but it returns empty list.   q = re.compile(r'"avgRating":(\d+),')
    ratings.append((q.findall(r.text)[0]))

Comment: have you tried debugging the script? Checking the regex works on source? That source contains value? Seems likely there will be a different handler/endpoint. Take the js file and de-minify then look for the appropriate endpoint is part of the likely solution.